# Resample time-series of position evenly in time

Tags: python, interpolation, resampling

As often happens in Earth sciences, I have a time series of positions (lon,lat). The time series is not evenly spaced in time. The time sampling looks like :

```
    t_diff_every_position = [3.99, 1.00, 3.00, 4.00, 3.98, 3.99, ... ]
```

And I have associated position with every t :

```
   lat = [77.0591,  77.0547,  77.0537, 74.6766,  74.6693,  74.6725, ... ]
   lon = [-135.2876, -135.2825, -135.2776, -143.7432, -143.7994,
   -143.8582, ... ]
```

I want to re-sample the positions to have a dataset evenly spaced in time. So I want the time vector to look like :

```
    t_resampled = [4.00, 4.00, 4.00, 4.00, 4.00, 4.00, ... ]
```

and have the associated position from an interpolation.

The positions do not follow a monotonic function, so I can't use the usual re-sampling and interpolation functions from scipy. [Positions with time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxTQ.png)

Does anyone have an idea about how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to interpolate the longitudes and latitudes separately. Here's an example with some simulated data.

Suppose we have 100 longitudes (`lon`), latitudes (`lat`), and timestamps (`t`). The time is irregular:

```
>>> t
array([ 0.        ,  1.09511126,  1.99576514,  2.65742629,  3.35929893,
        4.1379694 ,  5.55703942,  6.52892196,  7.64924527,  8.60496239])
```

And the path drawn by these coordinates looks something like:

[image]

We use scipy's `interp1d` to linearly interpolate the latitude and the longitude separately:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f_lon = interp1d(t, lon)
f_lat = interp1d(t, lat)
```

Then we make an array of regular timestamps, `[1, 2, 3, ..., 100]`, and resample our latitudes and longitudes:

```
reg_t = np.arange(0, 99)
reg_lon = f_lon(reg_t)
reg_lat = f_lat(reg_t)
```

The plots below show the result for interpolating on the regular interval `np.arange(0, 99, 5)`. This is a coarser interval than what you'd like, since it is quite difficult to see that there are in fact two functions in each plot if a finer interval is used.

[image]